# How to get start day timestamp and end day timestamp from value

Tags: sql, postgresql

For example I have one column `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` with value `'2017-07-09 19:43:54.418544'`
How to get from this value something like this :

```
2017-07-09 00:00:00 as start_day,
2017-07-09 23:59:59 as end_day
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That format is not a timestamp *with timezone*.  It doesn't have the timezone part.  But with or without, you can use `date_trunc()`:

```
select date_trunc('day', val) as start_day,
       (date_trunc('day', val) + interval '1 day' - interval '1 second') as end_day
```

I am not a fan of inclusive end-day bounds.  I would recommend just saying "< the start of the next day".

Comment: When I'm trying `select date_trunc(day, '2017-07-09 19:43:54.418544') as start_day,
       (date_trunc(day, '2017-07-09 19:43:54.418544') + interval '1 day' - interval '1 second') as end_day` have and error : `ERROR: column "day" does not exist`

Comment: @AbraKadabraa There is typo in the answer. 'day' should be quoted: `date_trunc('day', '2017-07-09 19:43:54.418544')`

Comment: i guess that `date_trunc('day', val) + interval '1 day'` can work as long as the start of the next day can be seen as the end of the current day. I mean  taking now as '2023-06-05' `this => date_trunc('day', computed.begins) as start_day, date_trunc('day', computed.ends + interval '1 day') as ends_day` procudes the following values `{"2023-06-05 00:00:00+00", "2023-06-06 00:00:00+00"}`